How to use a boolean in a function using Python
I'm trying to check if a condition is set in a function. This does not work and the global variable is always True. How can use a boolean variable that changes in the function?
flag = True

def check(x, y):
    if x > y:
        sumb=100
        flag=True
    else:
        sumb=10
        flag=False

    return sumb

result=check(10,20)
print(flag)

if flag == False:
    print("Yes")


If a variable is assigned inside a function, it is assumed to be a local variable in that function, even if a global variable with the same name already exists.

You need to add global flag before your code in the check function, like this:
def check(x, y):
    global flag
    if x > y:
        sumb=100
        flag=True
    else:
        sumb=10
        flag=False
    return sumb

This is required because Python has scopes, so if you set a variable outside of a scope (flag = True), you can read it and set it inside the scope, but when you leave the scope (return sumb), the changes are discarded. global prevents the changes from being discarded.
global is not recommended either way, so you should instead return flag like this:
return sumb, flag.
This will return a tuple containing sumb and flag, so you can access it like this:
sumb, flag = check(), or this:
a = check()
print(a[0]) # Sumb
print(a[1]) # Flag

